# Object field initialization and assignment

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a syntax way in CoffeeScript to do the listed below in more elegant way?

```
obj.field ?= {}
obj.field.value = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is

```
(obj.field ?= {}).value = 1
```

which is one line shorter, but I wouldn't say it's more elegant.